# Grails 3 with ajax dependency selection plugin not loading

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-3.0

I am trying to implement ajax dependancy selection plugin in Grails 3 project.

My project builds using

```
gradlew build
```

But when I click on

```
grails.plugin.ajaxdependancyselection.AutoCompleteController
```

link it gives

```
`Error: Page Not Found (404)
Path: /autoComplete/index`
```

error.

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry to hear you were having problems, I wrote the plugin ages ago and the best method to raise issues with a given plugin is to raise a request on the specific software [issue](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselection/issues) page.

But in all honesty if I had a penny each time someone hit an issue and I ended up replicating code only to not find any issues.

So:

> 1. What version of grails ?
> 2. What was the exact thing you tried.
> 3. [Did you refer to example / sample project](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testads). ?

I think if you had many of your answers would be answered.

In short I `created a grails 3.2.8 application, cloned the above project locally. Copied`

> grails-app/{views/*|domain/*|controllers/*|init/BootStrap.groovy}

from cloned project into locally created app and wolla it worked.